# Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ , where $A$ is normal and $A, B$ are unitarily similar. Prove that $B$ is normal.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is straight forward but I am struggling to link the facts together.

I know that $A$ is normal so $ A^*A=AA^* $. $A, B$ are unitarily similar so $ \exists U $ such that $U$ is unitary and $ B=U^*AU $. I also need to show that $B$ is normal, so $ B^*B=BB^* $.

I'm assuming that the solution is as simple as writing $ BB^*=(U^*AU)(U^*AU)^* $ and doing a similar thing for $ B^*B $ , and then using the fact that $A$ is normal to simplify, but I don't know where to go from the expression $ BB^*=(U^*AU)(U^*AU)^* $.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $(MN)^*=N^*M^*.$ And if $U$ is unitary then $UU^*=I.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thankyou, this is what I was missing, the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

The following two hints should suffice:

- $(MN)^*=N^*M^*.$
- If $U$ is unitary then $UU^∗=I.$

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I have solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B = U^*AU$. Then,
$$BB^* = (U^*AU)(U^*AU)^* = U^*AUU^*A^*U = U^*AA^*U = U^*A^*AU$$
Can you finish it from here?